# delphi textrect wordwrap

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-7

I am using Canvas.TextRect in Delphi 7 to output something on the screen.

I need my text to be word wrapped in the rectangle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use DrawText (or DrawTextEx) with the DT_WORDBREAK flag.

See the sample in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.using/browse_thread/thread/6e7afd9026d743a6/b786170fba9eb30e?lnk=st&q=delphi+tstringgrid+multi+line&rnum=3&pli=1).

Comment: Following up -- that sample has a call to "SetGridHeight".  Where does that come from?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
DrawText( hdc, pchar(s), length(s), rcRect, DT_NOPREFIX or DT_WORDBREAK);
```

where

`s` : string to print

`rcRect` : TRect the rect wherein the string should be printed.