# Delphi7 Canvas.TextOut can't write new lines

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, newline

I am trying to replace all "#" with new lines to draw:

```
Canvas.TextOut(0,0,''+StringReplace('a#b','#',#13#10,[rfReplaceAll]));
```

but nothing. 
TextOut prints "a#b" like the the replaced part doesn't even exist (But it does exist ofcourse): `ab`
Instead of this:

```
a
b
```

`#13#10` is the new line (Windows) right?
Then why this isn't working?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, `TextOut` cannot handle multiple lines. Try using `DrawText` or `DrawTextEx` with `DT_WORDBREAK`. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648277/delphi-textrect-wordwrap

Comment: Another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719025/delphi-drawing-text-to-canvas-word-wrap-and-measuring-size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `DrawText` to produce multi-line text:

```
var
  R: TRect;
....
R := Rect(0, 0, Width, Height);
DrawText(
  Canvas.Handle,
  PChar(StringReplace('a#b','#',#13#10,[rfReplaceAll])),
  -1,
  R,
  0
);
```

You may very well want to use different flags in the final parameter, but I'm sure you can read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498.aspx) and work out what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Textout is basically a wrapper for Windows.ExtTextOut which doesn't support multiple lines. An alternative is to use DrawText:

```
var
  r: TRect
  s: string
begin
  s := StringReplace('a#b','#',#13#10,[rfReplaceAll]);
  r.Left := 10;
  r.Top := 10;
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PWideChar(s), Length(s), r, DT_NOPREFIX or DT_WORDBREAK);
end;
```

If you're using Delphi 7 then you will probably want to replace the PWideChar with PChar.

Comment: You can use `PChar` instead of `PWideChar` since the `DrawText` is in non Unicode Delphi mapped to the `DrawTextA` and in Unicode versions of Delphi to `DrawTextW`. And the `PChar` is `PWideChar` in Unicode versions and `PAnsiChar` in non Unicode.