# Adding a new line to a canvas.textout

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to put this to the canvas text out

Name
Flying
Lava
Water

Doing it like so.. it checks if the player should have something under there name like flying,lava,or water.  So label text starts as the players name. All labels will have this. and then if any of the "extras" like canwater are true then it will add a new line with the related text. Seen below.

```
                canwater := (FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(name2)].values['water'] = 'Yes');  //checks if unit can enter water
                canlava := (FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(name2)].values['lava'] = 'Yes');  //checks if unit can enter lava
                canfly := (FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(name2)].values['Flying'] = 'Yes');   //checks if unit can fly
                labeltext :=  FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(name2)].values['name'];
               if canfly then
                  labeltext := labeltext+ #13#10+ 'Flying';
               if canlava then
                  labeltext := Labeltext+#13#10+'Lava';
               if canwater then
                  labeltext := labeltext+#13#10+'Water';
               hexmap1.AddLabelName(Labeltext,posL); //add name to placement label
```

Now it will give the correct info to the caption. But it never adds the new line, instead it will look something like this

```
name[][]flying[][]lava[][]water[][]
```

where [] are small squares
The code i am using for the textout looks like this.

```
procedure THexmap.AddLabelName(text :string; Position :TPoint);
var
  hex_id :string;
  P0:tpoint;

begin
    with TempMap.canvas do
   begin
      hex_id := text;
           hex_id := text;
           {font := self.font;}
           p0 := convertcoords(point(Position.X,Position.Y),ptROWCOL);
           textout(p0.x - (trunc(textwidth(hex_id) / 2)) ,p0.y- (textheight(hex_id)) ,hex_id);
   end;
       Refresh;
end;
```

pretty much it loads the new images or in this case text, to a temp map.. the hex_ID is the name/flying/lava..ect  the PO is Where to put it on the map aka  row 1 , column 3.  As for the textout, i am not sure how that works.. But figure the "newline" code #10#13 is getting messed up there. So any ideas on how i can fix this?

added how i get my XY(tpoint)

```
{******************************************************************************}
{  This function will return the Row / Col pair based on a given X/Y
   for a using application that calls it}
 function THexMap.ConvertCoords(point:Tpoint;pointtype:Tpointtype):Tpoint;
 var
   temp:TPoint;
 begin
   case PointType of
     ptXY: {Convert from x/y to Row/Col}
     Begin

       temp.x:= round( (point.x + (HexRadius/2) ) / (1.5 * Hexradius));



       if odd(temp.x) then
          temp.y := round( (point.y + rise) / (rise*2))
       else
          temp.y := round( point.y  / (2*rise));

       { This section insures row / col is good}
      if (temp.x < 1) or (temp.y < 1) then
         begin
           temp.x := 0;
           temp.y := 0;
          end
       else if (temp.y > HexRows) or (temp.x > HexColumns) then
         begin
           temp.y := 0;
           temp.x := 0;
         end;

       ConvertCoords := temp;
     end;

     ptRowCol:  { Converts Row/Col to X/Y }
     begin
       if point.x=1 then
        temp.x:= HexRadius
       else
        temp.x := HexRadius+(point.x-1) * (round(1.5 * hexradius));

       if odd(point.x) then
        if point.y=1 then
           temp.y:= rise
        else
           temp.y := rise+(point.y-1) * (2 * rise)
       else
         temp.y := (point.y * (2*rise));

       ConvertCoords := temp;
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: i did see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277324/delphi7-canvas-textout-cant-write-new-lines  but not sure how i would do that with needing the PO (position on the map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextOut simply treats #13#10 as two characters to draw. That's why you see the squares.
It does not know that you intend to put the text on different lines.

You have to put the text to draw on different lines, e.g. by writing 4 calls to TextOut.

You could also use DrawText from the Win32 API.

Comment: if i did the 4 textout calls, it would just over write the old text.. is there no way to have textout read in a newline?

Comment: @GlenMorse you would not draw each line at the same position of course. Instead, you would use a different vertical position for each line.

Comment: i was really hopeing for an easier way :(  the reason is. The label moves when the players move there units.  Thus , I would have to 1. count and know how many lines on each unit to delete and redraw on a new hex when they move the unit. 2. Have to find out how i would know what line needs What amount added to the vertical.  3. The size of the hexes on the map will now play a huge part in the vertical placement.. I am starting to think I am better off not using anything more then just name :D

Comment: To calculate the text height with the current font, see [`TextHeight`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_TextHeight.html).

Comment: Use DrawText, it does all that for you. The only thing you have to do is: Read and understand the documentation. Not a big deal, don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

```
var
 s:String;
 r:TRect;
begin
   s := 'Just'#13#10'for'#13#10'demonstration';
   r.Left := 10;
   r.top := 10;
   r.Right := 100;
   r.Bottom := 100;

   // you can use this with newer Delphiversions
   // Canvas.TextRect(r,s, [tfCenter,tfWordBreak]);
   // with olderversions you can use this             =1              =16
   DrawTextEx(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s), Length(s), r, DT_CENTER or DT_WORDBREAK, nil);
end;
```

as answer of the question how to get rect from point

```
var
 s:String;
 r:TRect;
begin
   s := 'Just'#13#10'for'#13#10'demonstration';
   r.Left := p0.x;
   r.top := p0.y;
   r.Right := p0.x + 10000;    // we will calculate needed rect later
   r.Bottom := p0.y + 10000;   // via DT_CALCRECT

   // you can use this with newer Delphiversions
   // Canvas.TextRect(r,s, [tfCenter,tfWordBreak,tfCalcRect]);
   // with olderversions you can use this             =1              =16           1024
   DrawTextEx(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s), Length(s), r, DT_CENTER or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_CALCRECT, nil);

   // you can use this with newer Delphiversions
   // Canvas.TextRect(r,s, [tfCenter,tfWordBreak]);
   // with olderversions you can use this             =1              =16
   DrawTextEx(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s), Length(s), r, DT_CENTER or DT_WORDBREAK, nil);
end;
```

Comment: With the position, mine are in x , y coords (TPoint), and to make it worst the TPoint is converted to x,y of hexes. like so        position := hexmap1.convertcoords(point(x,y),ptXY);  //gets current position    Which is..well added it up top.. So how would i control R?

Comment: maybe I did't understand correctly the meaning of x,y and you will need something like :    Offsetrect(r, - (r.Right-r.Left) div 2,0);